# Removing alerts in a word document that is inside a web browser in c#

Tags: c#, browser

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Prototype
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        object oDocument;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application wordApp;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document doc; 

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Office Documents " + " " + "(*.doc, *.docx)|*.doc;*.docx";
            openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
            System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument document;
            string sFileName;
            openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            sFileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;

            if (sFileName.Length != 0)
            {
                oDocument = null;
                webBrowser1.Navigate(sFileName);
                document = webBrowser1.Document;
                wordApp = webBrowser1.Document;

            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /*
            if (sender.Equals(button9))
            {
                openFileDialog1.Filter = "Office Documents " + " " + "(*.doc, *.docx)|*.doc;*.docx";
            }
            else
                openFileDialog1.Filter = "Office Documents " + " " + "(*.doc, *.docx, *.xls, *.pptx, *.pdf, *.odt)|*.doc;*.docx;*.xls;*.pptx;*.pdf;*.odt"; ;

            openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;

            */

        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            oDocument = webBrowser1.Document;

        }

        private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Office Documents " + " " + "(*.xls, *.xlsx)|*.xls;*.xlsx";
            openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
            System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument document;
            string sFileName;
            openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            sFileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;

            if (sFileName.Length != 0)
            {
                oDocument = null;
                webBrowser1.Navigate(sFileName);
                document = webBrowser1.Document;

            }
        }

        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Office Documents " + " " + "(*.ppt, *.pptx)|*.ppt;*.pptx";
            openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
            System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument document;
            string sFileName;
            openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            sFileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;

            if (sFileName.Length != 0)
            {
                oDocument = null;
                webBrowser1.Navigate(sFileName);
                document = webBrowser1.Document;

            }
        }

        private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Office Documents " + " " + "(*.pdf)|*.pdf";
            openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
            System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument document;
            string sFileName;
            openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            sFileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;

            if (sFileName.Length != 0)
            {
                oDocument = null;
                webBrowser1.Navigate(sFileName);
                document = webBrowser1.Document;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

My code uses a web browser to display a word, excel, and powerpoint. Unfortunately every time it tries to open it, an alert box first appears and asks if i want to save or open or cancel. How am i suppose to remove it?

Comment: Does it *always* display a messagew box (also when yoe load the very first document), or only when you are loading the second, third etc. one?

Comment: Every single time. Help please.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into browser security. You can't just have documents that may contain malicious items in them open without user input.

Also... you need to refactor your code. There is so much code that you have that is the exact same.

```
 private string GetFileFromUser(string aFilter){
  openFileDialog1.Filter = aFilter
  openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
  System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument document;
  openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
  openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
  return openFileDialog1.FileName;
 }

 fileName = GetFileFromUser("Office Documents (*.xls, *.xlsx)|*.xls;*.xlsx");
```

Answer (score 0):

The way your doing it, the alert box will always show up unless you change your security settings in Internet Explorer. This is not advised and not even fesible if you are distributing to clients.

The better way to do this is to use [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [WebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to get the source of the HTML page. Then you should parse out the URL to the Word or Excel Document, then use can use WebRequest and WebResponse again to open the document and save it. From there you can use WebBrowser control to populate the Document property with the word or excel document.